# How to pass session data from collection to view? (Backbone JS / Coffeescript)

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a collection that contains these two functions:

```
class SomeCollection

handleData: (data) ->
  console.log JSON.stringify(data)
  return data

getData: ->
  Session.ajax
      url: "/some/endpoint/"
      type: ‘get'
```

Then I have view that calls the functions from the collection to return that session data:

```
class SomeView
initialize: =>
  @listenTo @collection

my_session_data = @collection.getData().done @collection.handleData

renderTable: =>
   @$el.html @template
   my_session_data: my_session_data
   console.log JSON.stringify(my_session_data)
```

Based on the console results, it looks like the console.log data from handleData() is appearing correctly. But when calling console.log from renderTable() it’s returning “undefined” in the console.

How can I get renderTable() from the view to return the data that seems to be working/appearing correctly in handleData()?

Answer (score 0):

Console.log function is asynchronous so you could have different results in the same time.